# Beans, Lists and JSP

Tags: jsp, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a little question...

On my JSP page I have a List of beans. I want to extract a sublist of beans with a specific property (Ex. all Horror books). Can Apache Beanutils help me?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a JSP you have 2 options:

1. Iterate over list yourself using JSTL `<c:forEach>` and test using JSTL `<c:if>` if the item matches the requirements and finally just display it.
2. Do the same in plain Java code and call this in a servlet prior to forwarding the request to the JSP. Optionally you can wrap this in an EL function so that you can call it from inside a JSP.

The Commons Beanutils can't help much here. It has as far as I know no collection filter with a predicate. The Commons Collections and Google Collections however have.